# How do I access the ith column of a NumPy multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Given:

```py
test = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

`test[i]` gives the *ith* row (e.g. `[1, 2]`). How do I access the *ith* column? (e.g. `[1, 3, 5]`). Also, would this be an expensive operation?

Answer (score 986, accepted):

With:

```
test = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

To access column 0:

```
>>> test[:, 0]
array([1, 3, 5])
```

To access row 0:

```
>>> test[0, :]
array([1, 2])
```

This is covered in Section 1.4 (Indexing) of the [NumPy reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).  This is quick, at least in my experience.  It's certainly much quicker than accessing each element in a loop.

Comment: This create a copy, is it possible to get reference, like I get a reference to a column, any change in this reference is reflected in the original array.

Comment: More helpful section of the docs: [Dimensional indexing tools](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#dimensional-indexing-tools)

Answer (score 104):

```
>>> test[:,0]
array([1, 3, 5])
```

this command gives you a row vector, if you just want to loop over it, it's fine, but if you want to hstack with some other array with dimension 3xN, you will have

> ```
> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
> ```

while

```
>>> test[:,[0]]
array([[1],
       [3],
       [5]])
```

gives you a column vector, so that you can do concatenate or hstack operation.

e.g.

```
>>> np.hstack((test, test[:,[0]]))
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [3, 4, 3],
       [5, 6, 5]])
```

Answer (score 93):

And if you want to access more than one column at a time you could do:

```
>>> test = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> test
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> test[:,[0,2]]
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 5],
       [6, 8]])
```

Comment: `test[:,[0,2]]` just accesses the data, e.g, `test[:, [0,2]] = something` would modify test, and not create another array. But `copy_test = test[:, [0,2]]` does in fact create a copy as you say.

Answer (score 25):

You could also transpose and return a row:

```
In [4]: test.T[0]
Out[4]: array([1, 3, 5])
```

Answer (score 23):

Although the question has been answered, let me mention some nuances.

Let's say you are interested in the first column of the array

```
arr = numpy.array([[1, 2],
                   [3, 4],
                   [5, 6]])
```

As you already know from other answers, to get it in the form of "row vector" (array of shape `(3,)`), you use slicing:

```
arr_col1_view = arr[:, 1]         # creates a view of the 1st column of the arr
arr_col1_copy = arr[:, 1].copy()  # creates a copy of the 1st column of the arr
```

To check if an array is a view or a copy of another array you can do the following:

```
arr_col1_view.base is arr  # True
arr_col1_copy.base is arr  # False
```

see [ndarray.base](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html).

Besides the obvious difference between the two (modifying `arr_col1_view` will affect the `arr`), the number of byte-steps for traversing each of them is different:

```
arr_col1_view.strides[0]  # 8 bytes
arr_col1_copy.strides[0]  # 4 bytes
```

see [strides](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097952/how-to-understand-numpy-strides-for-layman/53099870#53099870).

Why is this important? Imagine that you have a very big array `A` instead of the `arr`:

```
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(10000, 10000), dtype='int32')
A_col1_view = A[:, 1] 
A_col1_copy = A[:, 1].copy()
```

and you want to compute the sum of all the elements of the first column, i.e. `A_col1_view.sum()` or `A_col1_copy.sum()`. Using the copied version is much faster:

```
%timeit A_col1_view.sum()  # ~248 µs
%timeit A_col1_copy.sum()  # ~12.8 µs
```

This is due to the different number of strides mentioned before:

```
A_col1_view.strides[0]  # 40000 bytes
A_col1_copy.strides[0]  # 4 bytes
```

Although it might seem that using column copies is better, it is not always true for the reason that making a copy takes time too and uses more memory (in this case it took me approx. 200 µs to create the `A_col1_copy`). However if we needed the copy in the first place, or we need to do many different operations on a specific column of the array and we are ok with sacrificing memory for speed, then making a copy is the way to go.

In the case we are interested in working mostly with columns, it could be a good idea to create our array in column-major ('F') order instead of the row-major ('C') order (which is the default), and then do the slicing as before to get a column without copying it:

```
A = np.asfortranarray(A)   # or np.array(A, order='F')
A_col1_view = A[:, 1]
A_col1_view.strides[0]     # 4 bytes

%timeit A_col1_view.sum()  # ~12.6 µs vs ~248 µs
```

Now, performing the sum operation (or any other) on a column-view is as fast as performing it on a column copy.

Finally let me note that transposing an array and using row-slicing is the same as using the column-slicing on the original array, because transposing is done by just swapping the shape and the strides of the original array.

```
A[:, 1].strides[0]    # 40000 bytes
A.T[1, :].strides[0]  # 40000 bytes
```

Answer (score 9):

To get several and indepent columns, just:

```
> test[:,[0,2]]
```

you will get colums 0 and 2

Comment: How is this any different from Akavall's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16121210/369450)?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> test
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

>>> ncol = test.shape[1]
>>> ncol
5L
```

Then you can select the 2nd - 4th column this way:

```
>>> test[0:, 1:(ncol - 1)]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not multidimensional. It is 2 dimensional array. where you want to access the columns you wish.

```
test = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
test[:, a:b]  # you can provide index in place of a and b
```

Comment: `2` is a 'multi'.  `multidimensional` is not limited to 3 or 4 or more.  The base array class in `numpy` is `ndarray`, where the `n` stands for any number from 0 up.  2 dimensional is not a special case, except that it fits our intuitions about rows and columns the best.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered but a note on view vs copy.

If the array is indexed using a scalar (regular indexing), the result is a view (`x` below) which means whatever change made to `x` will reflect on `test` because `x` is just a different view of `test`.

```py
test = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
# select second column
x = test[:, 1]
x[:] = 100        # <---- this does affects test

test
array([[  1, 100],
       [  3, 100],
       [  5, 100]])
```

However, if the array is indexed using a list/array-like (advanced indexing), the result is a copy, which means any changes to `x` will not affect `test`.

```py
test = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
# select second column
x = test[:, [1]]
x[:] = 100        # <---- this does not affect test

test
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

---

In general, using a slice to index will return a view:

```py
test = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
x = test[:, :2]
x[:] = 100

test
array([[100, 100],
       [100, 100],
       [100, 100]])
```

but using an array to index will return a copy:

```py
test = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
x = test[:, np.r_[:2]]
x[:] = 100

test
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Regular indexing is extremely fast and advanced indexing is much slower (that said, it's still almost instantaneous and it certainly will not be a bottleneck in the program).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to clarify harmand's comment under mtrw's highest score answer is confusing. He says:

> This create a copy, is it possible to get reference, like I get a reference to a column, any change in this reference is reflected in the original array.

While actually this code

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

barr = arr[:, 1]

print(barr)

barr[1] = 8

print(arr)
```

prints out

```
[[1 2]
 [3 8]
 [5 6]]
```

I would appreciate if you note this in the comments under mtrw's answer as my reputation is too low yet.