# Numpy how to iterate over columns of array?

Tags: python, loops, numpy

Suppose I have and m x n array.  I want to pass each column of this array to a function to perform some operation on the entire column.  How do I iterate over the columns of the array?

For example, I have a 4 x 3 array like

```
1  99 2
2  14 5
3  12 7
4  43 1

for column in array:
  some_function(column)
```

where column would be "1,2,3,4" in the first iteration, "99,14,12,43" in the second, and "2,5,7,1" in the third.

Comment: Can't you use an index --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/numpy-access-an-array-by-column

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Just iterate over the transposed of your array:

```
for column in array.T:
   some_function(column)
```

Comment: What would be a good way to combine the result back into a single array?

Comment: For those wondering, `array.T` isn't costly, as it just changes the 'strides' of `array` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19479436/420867) for an interesting discussion)

Comment: Is there a way of iterating which keeps the vectors as column vectors?

Answer (score 29):

This should give you a start

```
>>> for col in range(arr.shape[1]):
    some_function(arr[:,col])


[1 2 3 4]
[99 14 12 43]
[2 5 7 1]
```

Comment: It doesn't look pythonic to me.

Comment: @gronostaj Of course it's Pythonic.  How else would you solve this problem when you want to iterate over an arbitrary axis of a multidimensional array?

Comment: @NeilG This question is strictly about 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Accepted answer looks good on SO. This saves the day!

Answer (score 8):

For a three dimensional array you could try:

```
for c in array.transpose(1, 0, 2):
    do_stuff(c)
```

See the docs on how [`array.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) works. Basically you are specifying which dimension to shift. In this case we are shifting the second dimension (e.g. columns) to the first dimension.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use unzip to iterate through the columns

```
for col in zip(*array):
   some_function(col)
```

Comment: Interesting. This returns tuples instead of arrays.  And it's much faster.

Comment: I have a hunch that the result of this might depend on the storage order of the numpy array ('C' or 'F') - it may return columns in one case and rows in the other. I'm not sure though - just a warning, better check before using this. It doesn't look safe.

Answer (score 4):

```
for c in np.hsplit(array, array.shape[1]):
    some_fun(c)
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is old but for anyone looking nowadays.

You can iterate through the rows of a numpy array like this:

```
for row in array:
    some_function(row) # do something here
```

So to iterate through the columns of a 2D array you can simply transpose it like this:

```
transposed_array = array.T

#Now you can iterate through the columns like this:
for column in transposed_array:
    some_function(column) # do something here
```

If you want to collect the results of each column into a list for example, you can use list comprehension.

```
[some_function(column) for column in array.T]
```

So in summary you can perform a function on each column of an array and collect the results into a list using this line of code:

```
result_list = [some_function(column) for column in array.T]
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you want to find a mean of each column in matrix. Let's create the following matrix

```
mat2 = np.array([1,5,6,7,3,0,3,5,9,10,8,0], dtype=np.float64).reshape(3, 4)
```

The function for mean is

```
def my_mean(x):
    return sum(x)/len(x)
```

To do what is needed and store result in colon vector 'results'

```
results = np.zeros(4)
for i in range(0, 4):
    mat2[:, i] = my_mean(mat2[:, i])

results = mat2[1,:]
```

The results are: 
array([4.33333333, 5.        , 5.66666667, 4.        ])

Answer (score 0):

NumPy arrays have built-in methods for stuff like this.

```
print(list(T.mean(axis=0)))
# [2.5, 42.0, 3.75]
```

In 2-dim arrays, axis 0 is the column dimension.

Sorry I answered this 10 years & 4 months too late.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can use `enumerate`. It gives you the column number and the column values as well.

```
for num, column in enumerate(array.T):
    some_function(column) # column: Gives you the column value as asked in the question
    some_function(num) # num: Gives you the column number
```

Comment: This isn't really adding anything to solve the problem. The problem doesn't ask for indices, just columns, and `enumerate` is a general Python utility unrelated to `numpy`. `array.T` was posted years ago.

Answer (score -1):

list -> array -> matrix -> matrix.T

```
import numpy as np

list = [1, 99, 2, 2, 14, 5, 3, 12, 7, 4, 43, 1]
arr_n = np.array(list) # list -> array
print(arr_n)
matrix = arr_n.reshape(4, 3) # array -> matrix(4*3）
print(matrix)
print(matrix.T) # matrix -> matrix.T



[ 1 99  2  2 14  5  3 12  7  4 43  1]

[[ 1 99  2]
 [ 2 14  5]
 [ 3 12  7]
 [ 4 43  1]]

[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [99 14 12 43]
 [ 2  5  7  1]]
```