# Is numpy.transpose reordering data in memory?

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy

In order to speed up the functions like np.std, np.sum etc along an axis of an n dimensional huge numpy array, it is recommended to apply along the last axis.

When I do, np.transpose to rotate the axis I want to operate, to the last axis. Is it really reshuffling the data in memory, or just changing the way the axis are addressed?

When i tried to measure the time using %timeit. it was doing this transpose in micro seconds, (much smaller than the time required to copy the (112x1024x1024) array i was having.

If it is not actually reordering the data in memory and only changing the addressing, will it still speed up the np.sum or np.std when applied to newly rotated last axis?

When i tried to measure it, i does seem to speed up. But i don't understand how.

### Update

It doesn't really seem to speed up with transpose. The fastest axis is last one when it is C-ordered, and first one when it is Fortran-ordered. So there is no point in transposing before applying np.sum or np.std. 
For my specific code, i solved the issue by giving order='FORTRAN' during the array creation. Which made the first axis fastest.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Transpose just changes the [strides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array), it doesn't touch the actual array. I think the reason why `sum` etc. along the final axis is recommended (I'd like to see the source for that, btw.) is that when an array is C-ordered, walking along the final axis preserves locality of reference. That won't be the case after you transpose, since the transposed array will be Fortran-ordered.

Comment: Oh, okay. So is it correct to say that, to improve speed along an axis, there is no point in transposing it first and then applying the sum?

Comment: @indiajoe: you should measure to find out (maybe there's some optimization in NumPy that I'm not aware of), but I'd be very surprised if it caused a significant speed difference.

Comment: @indiajoe, measure. The only thing I could somewhat imagine is that some temporary arrays happen to have a more efficient layout then. But I would not really expect it, though more likely on older numpy <1.7. maybe.

Comment: @larsmans,@seberg : I tried to measure now. It looks like, the fastest axis always remains same. no matter how you transpose. When in C-ordered, the last axis is the fastest, and when in Fortran-ordered, the first axis is the fastest.
So, I think i can safely conclude that these is no point in transposing for speeding up an operation. When i create the array itself should give order= argument to optimise.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on larsman's answer, here are some timings:

```
# normal C (row-major) order array
>>> %%timeit a = np.random.randn(500, 400)
>>> np.sum(a, axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 272 us per loop

# transposing and summing along the first axis makes no real difference 
# to performance
>>> %%timeit a = np.random.randn(500, 400)
>>> np.sum(a.T, axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 269 us per loop

# however, converting to Fortran (column-major) order does improve speed...
>>> %%timeit a = np.asfortranarray(np.random.randn(500,400))
>>> np.sum(a, axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 114 us per loop

# ... but only if you don't count the conversion in the timed operations
>>> %%timeit a = np.random.randn(500, 400)
>>> np.sum(np.asfortranarray(a), axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 599 us per loop
```

In summary, it might make sense to convert your arrays to Fortran order if you're going to apply a lot of operations over the columns, but the conversion itself is costly and almost certainly not worth it for a single operation.

Comment: Thanks. that is what i did in the end. I converted the array to fortran order at the generation of array itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a physical reorg with `np.ascontinguousarray`.  For example...

```
a = np.ascontiguousarray(a.transpose())
```