# Create 3D Tensor From Vector

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I a have a vector

```
In [26]: x                                                                      
Out[26]: array([1, 2])
```

And I have a 3D tensor `a` with shape `(10,2,30)`, its content is `True,False`. I have to multiplicate every `a[i,:,:]` for `x[i]`.
I thought to `numpy.tile` but it does not work.

There is way to do it by avoiding for-loops?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Made solution better, first solution used a some unnecessary transposing.

For this kind of operation np.tensordot and np.einsum can be your friend. They can be hard getting used to, so i did it this way: (note that transposing and reshaping arrays in numpy is *very* fast, it only requires changing the *strides* of the array, so the time it takes does not increase with the size of your data set, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479384/is-numpy-transpose-reordering-data-in-memory).

```
a = np.array([0,10])
b = np.arange(600).reshape(10,2,30)

#making a same dimention as b
a = a.reshape((1,2,1))
c = a*b
```

We want to multiply a and b along some axis, so we reshape a to make the arrays match along that axis, then we multiply them.

There is very likely a more elegant way to do this, but it works, and is quite fast (0.004s if a has length 20 and b is shape (100, 20, 300).