# How to cycle through an image from top to bottom in python?

Tags: python, image, coordinates

I want to cycle through top to bottom instead of left to right on an image. (0,0 starts from top left)

```
    for y in range(image.height): # getting pixels
        for x in range(image.width):
             pixel = image.get_pixel(y,x) #invert coordinates to move down
```

I tried inverting the coordinates but it doesn't work on images that are not square.

Comment: I would prefer using numpy package for manipulating arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148818/numpy-how-to-iterate-over-columns-of-array

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, please? Iterating through images with `for` loops in Python should really be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Inverting the coordinates doesn't work on an image that is not square because you go beyond the width or height.  For example, in a 4x6 image, you can get a pixel at x, y == 4, 6, but if you ask for the pixel at x, y == 6, 4, it does not exist -- there is no pixel at x == 6.