# Is there a way to do this kind of list comprehension inside another loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary in python that is basically like this:

```
forecast = {"Name 1" : {list 1:\[ 0, 1, 2, 3\], list 2 : \[ 4, 5, 6, 7\]...}, "Name 2": {"list 1":\[\] , 'list 2': \[\] ...} }.
```

Which is a bunch of sampled data from a list of probability distributions from "Name 1", "Name 2" etc.

I want to use it to forecast different scenarios in a sort of simulation, using some machine learning models that I've already build, if I run something like pd.DataFrame(forecast['Name 1']).values[2], the data inside is already on the format that I need, but since I want to perform several predictions I tried something like:

```
for i in list:
        a = pd.DataFrame(forecast[i[0]]).values[j for j in len(forecast[i[0]])]
        b = pd.DataFrame(forecast[i[1]]).values[j for j in len(forecast[i[0]])]

but it gives the following error: 

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_4823/3184712350.py", line 5
    a = pd.DataFrame(forecast[i[0]]).values[j for j in len(forecast[i[0]])]
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I access the data to use with my models? I don't know if a for loop inside another will work, at least I can't think of a way that it could work. Can someone help?

Comment: What do you think looping over an integer is supposed to do? You're looping over the result of `len`, which is the length of `forecast[i[0]]`. That's like say `[x for x in 12]`, it doesn't make any sense. It makes even less sense using it as an index into `.values`, but even before we get there, I'm not sure what your loop is supposed to *do*.

Comment: as a pandas dataframe Forecast[i[0]] gives me a m by n dataframe, forecast[i[0]].values[1] for exemple, gives me one column of the dataframe, i want to parse the dataframe column by column

Answer (score 0):

The `.values` of a `DataFrame` is a `numpy` `array`. Iterating over the columns isn't done with indexing, you [just transpose the whole array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10148818/364696) and iterate over the transpose:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(forecast[i[0]]).values.T  # .T gets the transpose
for col in a:
    print(col)  # Displays a single column at a time
```

There are other, more complicated ways to go about it shown on the linked question, but really, all you need to know is that `.values` is a multidimensional `numpy.array`, so anything that works for `numpy.array` applies here.