# Getting only particular columns in every row in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [numpy: access an array by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/numpy-access-an-array-by-column)

I have a numpy array (numpy is imported as np)

```
gona = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

I can get the values of entire column of 1th row by gona[1][:].

> array([4, 5, 6])

But if I try to get all values of a particular column of all rows (say I want values of 1st column in every row) I would try the gona[:][1]. But the result I get from this is same as before.

What can be the reason for this? How do I do such a thing in numpy?

Comment: no.
I wanted know why both ways give same results too

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You actually want to do this:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
>>> a[:,1]
array([ 2,  5,  8, 11])
```

`a[:]` just returns the entire array, so then `a[:][1]` is returning the second row of `a`.  I think that's where your confusion arises.

See [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c) section of the [Tentative Numpy Tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) for more information on indexing multidimensional arrays.

Comment: `a[:][1]` selects the second row

Comment: Oops. You're right. I've corrected that.

Comment: This did the job.
Thank you

Comment: What does the comma mean?

Comment: The comma is the axis delimiter, so in this example, I'm selecting all elements along the first axis, and only the second element along the second axis.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be a slight confusion in terms of the positioning of the braces, `gona[:][1]` first selects everything from the array, and from that array then selects the second row. To select particular columns you put the indices within the same square brackets separated by a comma:

```
gona = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])

gona[1,:]
Out[21]: array([4, 5, 6])

gona[:,1]
Out[22]: array([ 2,  5,  8, 11])

gona[:,0]
Out[23]: array([ 1,  4,  7, 10])
```

you can also just select a range of rows for instance

```
gona[0:2,0] # only take the two first rows of the first column
Out[24]: array([2, 5])
```

Comment: thank you separately for selecting a range of rows code :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
gona = numpy.array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])

# List comprehension, just get each element in 'gona', and then get first element in that list
out = [x[0] for x in gona]

print out
```

Output:

```
>>> 
[1, 4, 7, 10]
>>>
```