# Access a column in a numpy array of different types?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the following array:

```
a = array([(1L, 2.0, 'buckle_my_shoe'), (3L, 4.0, 'margery_door')], 
dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', 'S14')])
```

How do I access a column?

I can access a row using this syntax:

```
a[0][:]
```

but get an error when I try to access a column in the same way.

```
a[:][0]
```

Note. This is not a dupe of "[How to access the ith column of a NumPy multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/numpy-access-an-array-by-column)" since I am using an array of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [33]: a['f0']
Out[33]: array([1, 3], dtype=int64)

In [34]: a['f1']
Out[34]: array([ 2.,  4.])

In [35]: a['f2']
Out[35]: 
array(['buckle_my_shoe', 'margery_door'], 
      dtype='|S14')
```

Here, `f0`, `f1` and `f2` are the field names from your array's `dtype`.

For more information, see [Structured Arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).