# How to replace one column by a value in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like this

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=np.int)
```

I want to replace the first column by the value `1`. I did the following:

```
a[:][0] = [1, 1] # not working
a[:][0] = [[1], [1]] # not working
```

Contrariwise, when I replace the rows it worked!

```
a[0][:] = [1, 1] # working
```

I have a big array, so I cannot replace value by value.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can replace the first column as follows:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=np.int)
>>> a[:, 0] =  1
>>> a
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

Here `a[:, 0]` means "select all rows from column 0". The value `1` is broadcast across this selected column, producing the desired array (it's not necessary to use a list `[1, 1]`, although you can).

Your syntax `a[:][0]` means "select all the rows from the array `a` and then select the first row". Similarly, `a[0][:]` means "select the first row of `a` and then select this entire row again". This is why you could replace the rows successfully, but not the columns - it's necessary to make a selection for axis 1, not just axis 0.

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=np.int)
a[:,0] = np.ones((1,2), dtype=np.int)
```

Please refer to [Accessing np matrix columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/numpy-access-an-array-by-column)

Answer (score 5):

Select the intended column using a proper indexing and just assign the value to it using `=`. Numpy will take care of the rest for you.

```
>>> a[::,0] = 1
>>> a
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

Read more about [numpy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).