# How to Print a specific column in a 3D Matrix using numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with printing a column in a numpy 3D Matrix.
Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
Matrix = np.zeros(((10,9,3))) # Creates a 10 x 9 x 3 3D matrix
Matrix[2][2][6] = 578
# I want to print Matrix[2][x][6] for x in range(9)
# the purpose of this is that I want to get all the Values in Matrix[2][x][6]
```

Much appreciated if you guys can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Matrix[2][2][6] = 578` gives an `IndexError` because your last dimension is not big enough for the index `6`.  This would work `Matrix[6][2][2] = 578`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if Numpy supports this, but you can do it with normal lists this way:

If you have three lists `a = [1,2,3]`, `b = [4,5,6]`, and `c = [7,8,9]`, you can get the second dimension `[2,5,8]` for example by doing

```
list(zip(a,b,c))[1]
```

EDIT:

Turns out this is pretty simple in Numpy. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/numpy-access-an-array-by-column) you can just do:

```
Matrix[:,1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yasser You made my day :D

Answer (score 3):

Slicing would work:

```
a = np.zeros((10, 9, 3))
a[6, 2, 2] = 578
for x in a[6, :, 2]:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.0
578.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  mike :)

Answer (score 1):

No sure if this is what you want. Here is demo:

```
In [1]: x = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(4, 5, 3))

In [2]: x
Out[2]: 
array([[[ 5, 13,  9],
        [ 8, 16,  5],
        [15, 17,  1],
        [ 6, 14,  5],
        [11, 13,  9]],

       [[ 5,  8,  0],
        [ 8, 15,  5],
        [ 9,  2, 13],
        [18,  4, 14],
        [ 8,  3, 13]],

       [[ 3,  7,  4],
        [15, 11,  6],
        [ 7,  8, 14],
        [12,  8, 18],
        [ 4,  2,  8]],

       [[10,  1, 16],
        [ 5,  2,  1],
        [11, 12, 13],
        [11,  9,  1],
        [14,  5,  1]]])

In [4]: x[:, 2, :]
Out[4]: 
array([[15, 17,  1],
       [ 9,  2, 13],
       [ 7,  8, 14],
       [11, 12, 13]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort sudipta as yasser pointed out, it is very simple as matrix[:,:,1] bit tricky isnt it :) Thanks again.