# How do I count the number of nonzero values in a given array column?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, count

I have an array that is as follows:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1],
 etc
```

I'd like to determine the sum of index [3] in each line. 
For example, here I'd like to get `2` as a result.

I'm trying

```
np.sum(np.count_nonzero(array[:][3], axis=1))
```

but I get an out of bounds error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to index the array as `a[:, 3]` (the third column of all rows), then you can do:

```
# if the array contains only 0 and 1
a[:,3].sum()
# 2

# if the array can have other values besides 0 and 1
np.count_nonzero(a[:,3])
# 2
```

Here is more info about [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: is the `axis` correct? I still get the out of bounds error

Comment: If you extract values with `a[:,3]`, you get a 1d array, then you don't need the `axis` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the list as [`n[:,3]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/how-to-access-the-ith-column-of-a-numpy-multidimensional-array) then sum normally since summing zero does nothing:

```
>>> numpy.sum(n[:,3])
2
```