# Selecting specific groups of rows from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix of certain size (as an example let’s say we have a matrix '**A**' which has 5 rows and 10 columns). I want to **select a few columns** out of this numpy matrix (let’s say I want to select rows 2,3,4,7, 9) and create another matrix (B).

For example,

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(5, size=(5, 10))
print A

[[1 3 2 1 2 1 0 2 2 2]
 [2 2 4 4 1 3 4 1 4 4]
 [2 4 1 3 0 4 3 0 1 0]
 [4 4 1 3 0 4 4 1 3 1]
 [1 0 1 2 1 0 4 0 1 3]]
```

The resulting matrix B should be:

```
B = [[2 1 2 2 2]
     [4 4 1 1 4]
     [1 3 0 0 0]
     [1 3 0 1 1]
     [1 2 1 0 3]]
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean columns? You can try: `B = A[:, [2,3,4,7,9]]` if rows, then `B = A[[2,3,4]]`

Comment: This question has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/how-to-access-the-ith-column-of-a-numpy-multidimensional-array/16121210#16121210, but I am not sure if this a duplicate.

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE: Yes, I did mean columns. Sorry for the mistake. And, thanks very much for the reply. Your solution worked fantastically well. =)

Comment: Great! glad it was helpful.