# Slice array, but overlapped interval in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, slice

There are 3D-array in my data. I just want to slice 3D-array 2 by 2 by 2 with overlapped interval in Python.

Here is an example for 2D.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4;
     5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Also, this is what I expected after slicing the array in 2 by 2.

```
[1, 2;  [2, 3;  [3, 4;
 5, 6]   6, 7]   7, 8]
```

In 3D,

```
  [[[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]],

   [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]],

   [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]]
```

Like this,(maybe not exactly..)

```
 [1, 2   [2, 3
  4, 5]   5, 6]       ...
 [1, 2   [2, 3
  4, 5]   5, 6]
```

I think, by using np.split, I could slice the array, but without overlapped. Please give me some helpful tips.

Comment: `a = [1, 2, 3, 4;
     5, 6, 7, 8]` is invalid Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

> You should have a look at `numpy.ndarray.strides` and `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`

Tuple of bytes to step in each dimension when traversing an array.
The byte offset of element `(i[0], i[1], ..., i[n])` in an array `a` is:

```
offset = sum(np.array(i) * a.strides)
```

See also the numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html)

> Following a 2D example using strides:

```
x = np.arange(20).reshape([4, 5])
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

>>> from numpy.lib import stride_tricks
>>> stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(3, 2, 5),
                                strides=(20, 20, 4))
...
array([[[  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]],

       [[  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [ 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]])
```

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097952/how-to-understand-numpy-strides-for-layman) on Stackoverflow, where this example is from, to increase your understanding.