# Broadcasting with concatenate operator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, array-broadcasting

[numpy.broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) allows to perform basic operations (additions, multiplication, etc.) with arrays of different shapes (under certain conditions on these shapes). For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0])
>>> b = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> a[:, np.newaxis] + b
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [11., 12., 13.],
       [21., 22., 23.],
       [31., 32., 33.]])
```

Each element of the output array is the addition of the elements in the input arrays. This can be described as an 'outer addition operation'.

Is there a simple way to do this with the concatenation operator instead? In other words, is there a simple way to perform an 'outer concatenation operation'? Which means that, with the previous example, the output array should be:

```
array([[[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  3.]],

       [[10.,  1.],
        [10.,  2.],
        [10.,  3.]],

       [[20.,  1.],
        [20.,  2.],
        [20.,  3.]],

       [[30.,  1.],
        [30.,  2.],
        [30.,  3.]]])
```

With few tries, I came up with this solution using numpy.meshgrid but it looks quite under-optimized to me and might be improved:

```
>>> a = np.array([0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0])
>>> b = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> c,d = np.meshgrid(a,b)
>>> np.concatenate((c.T[..., None], d.T[..., None]), axis=-1)
array([[[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  3.]],

       [[10.,  1.],
        [10.,  2.],
        [10.,  3.]],

       [[20.,  1.],
        [20.,  2.],
        [20.,  3.]],

       [[30.,  1.],
        [30.,  2.],
        [30.,  3.]]])
```

Is there a more 'pythonic' way to do this?

Comment: This is a feature I miss often too... I usually go for `np.broadcast_arrays` to manually do the broadcast, then `np.stack` or `np.concatenate` them together.

Comment: Playing around with different stacks and broadcast orderings, I found: `np.dstack(np.broadcast_arrays(a[:, None], b))`

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs your solution is interesting as it allows to concatenate more than one array (as it is possible to do with regular broadcasting). `np.dstack(np.broadcast_arrays(a[:, None], b, c))` works as well.

Comment: `concatenate` (and `stack` derivatives) doesn't do `broadcasting`, nor is it an operator.  Your use of `meshgrid` replicates the inputs to a desired size; concatenate then joins them. I could have suggested using `repeat` and `tile`, but the idea using of `broadcast_arrays` is a good one.

Comment: does this work `np.array(np.meshgrid(a, b)).T`?? Parharps you want to use `itertools.product`

Comment: `broadcasting` is used when assigning values to a higher dimension array.  See the last and fastest version I tried.

Answer (score 2):

I added a fast broadcasted assignment solution at the end.

---

What does it mean to be more 'pythonic' (or in this case more 'numpy-onic')?

If it runs and produces the desire result, is that enough?  'one liners' are stylish in `perl`, but not `python`.  `broadcasting` is a valid concept when using operators like `+`, but `concatenate` isn't an operator.

In sense then we are left with comparing speeds.  But all speed tests need to be qualified by the size of the arrays.

Anyways for your test case:

```
In [33]: %%timeit 
    ...: c,d = np.meshgrid(a,b)
    ...: np.concatenate((c.T[..., None], d.T[..., None]), axis=-1)

82.7 µs ± 337 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The `broadcast_arrays` approach produces two arrays, similar to `meshgrid` (actually just their transpose):

```
In [34]: np.broadcast_arrays(a[:, None], b)
Out[34]: 
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [10., 10., 10.],
        [20., 20., 20.],
        [30., 30., 30.]]),
 array([[1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.]])]
```

Speed is slightly better, but not an 'order of magnitude':

```
In [35]: timeit np.stack(np.broadcast_arrays(a[:, None], b),axis=2)
77.4 µs ± 2.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

But we can construct the same `broadcasted` arrays with `repeat` (that's a good compiled numpy method):

```
In [36]: (a[:,None].repeat(3,axis=1), b[None,:].repeat(4, axis=0))
Out[36]: 
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [10., 10., 10.],
        [20., 20., 20.],
        [30., 30., 30.]]),
 array([[1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.]]))
```

And surprise, it's faster:

```
In [37]: timeit np.stack((a[:,None].repeat(3,axis=1), b[None,:].repeat(4, axis=0)),axis=2)
29.7 µs ± 99.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

So which is more 'pythonic'?  For this small example the repeat is faster, even if it is 'wordier'.  My guess is that for much larger arrays, the `broadcast_arrays` will scale better.

### broadcasting code

Someone found and down-voted my answer to a previous broadcasting question

[what happens under the hood of broadcasting a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125558/what-happens-under-the-hood-of-broadcasting-a-numpy-array)

Comments suggest looking at the source code found in `np.lib.stride_tricks`.

`broadcast_array` is python code, and uses `_broadcast_to`.  That in turn uses `np.nditer`.  That's known to be slow, at least in the python interface version.

The arrays produced by `meshgrid` and my `repeats` are copies.  But the arrays produced by `broadcast_arrays` (`Out[34]`), are views, created from `a` and `b` by playing with the `shape` and `strides`.  Normally making a view is fast since it doesn't have to copy the `base` values.  But my guess is that the setup code for the `stride_tricks` functions is time consuming.

```
In [44]: _34[0].base
Out[44]: array([ 0., 10., 20., 30.])

In [45]: _34[1].base
Out[45]: array([1., 2., 3.])

In [46]: _34[0].strides, _34[1].strides
Out[46]: ((8, 0), (0, 8))
```

As suggested by the module name, `stride_tricks`, using this `broadcast_arrays` function is a nice, cute trick, but not essential to understanding or using `numpy`, and especially not the normal use of `broadcasting` with operators.

### broadcasted assignment

Here's an even better version.  Instead of using concatenate, it makes the target array directly, and fills it in with values from `a` and `b`:

```
In [75]: timeit res=np.empty((4,3,2)); res[:,:,0]=a[:,None]; res[:,:,1]=b
4.56 µs ± 14 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

This does utilize `broadcasting`, as can be seen with an erronious assignment:

```
In [76]: res=np.empty((4,3,2)); res[:,:,0]=a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[76], line 1
----> 1 res=np.empty((4,3,2)); res[:,:,0]=a

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,) into shape (4,3)
```

`broadcasting` is not just used by binary operators, it is also used during `advanced indexing`, and as shown here when assigning values to a slice of an array.

Here a (4,1) `a` can fit the (4,3) slot, and (3,) `b` can also fit that size slot.

Comment: Thank you for your (very) detailed answer! Your last comment is perhaps the closest to what I had in mind by saying use broadcast for concatenation or by saying "pythonic" (sorry for the vagueness of this term...)

Comment: I had to step back from the problem as  you presented it - the concatenate as operator - and let my mind visualize a different task.  To me, programming, especially with numpy, is almost a visual task.