# Elementwise insertion of array into array using numpy

Tags: numpy

Let's say I have an array of years created like

```
years = np.arange(2024,2051,1)
```

And I have an array of months created like

```
months = np.arange(1,13,1)
```

What is the most pythonic way of arriving at an elementwise concatenation such that the end result is

[[2024,1],[2024,2],[2024,3]...[2024,12],
[2025,1],[2025,2],[2025,3]...[2025,12],
...
]

?

Thanks

Comment: Your subject line talks about 'insertion', while question asks about 'concatenate'.  Have you considered making `np.zeros((n.m,2))` array, and assigning the arrays to it?  That's a kind of insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the most pythonic is:

```
out = [[year, month] for year in years for month in months]
```

There is also [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but it will give you a list of tuples.

```
from itertools import product
out = list(product(years, months))
```

If you want to be full numpy, you can take advantage of broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np
out = np.dstack(np.broadcast_arrays(*np.ix_(years, months)))
```

- [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) reshapes the input arrays to be `(n_years, 1), (1, n_months)`
- [`np.broadcast_arrays`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html) creates views of `(n_years, n_months), (n_years, n_months)`
- [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) concatenates the above such that you get a `(n_years, n_months, 2)` array.

Edit:

I just realised that `np.ix_` + `np.broadcast_arrays` is more or less a `np.meshgrid`:

```
out = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(years, months, indexing="ij"))
```

Comment: In a recent answer to a similar question, I found that the best (fastest) use of broadcasting was to assign the arrays to a predefined `zeros` array. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78110268/901925