expand numpy array with a new dimension
arr = np.array([[1,2],
                [2,3],
                [5,6]])

Is there any numpy function to clone the above 2d array into 3d array as shown below? If not, how to do it with multiple steps?
bb = np.?????(arr, 3)
>> print(bb)

[[[1,2],
   [2,3],
   [5,6]],
 [[1,2],
  [2,3],
  [5,6]],
 [[1,2],
  [2,3],
  [5,6]]]


While the dimension expansion is different, I explored some alternatives in https://stackoverflow.com/q/78106933/901925

You can make your own custom function like this:
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2],
                [2,3],
                [5,6]])
def to_3d(arr, n): 
    l = (arr for _ in range(n))
    return np.array(list(l))
print (to_3d(arr, 3))

Output:
[[[1 2]
  [2 3]
  [5 6]]

 [[1 2]
  [2 3]
  [5 6]]

 [[1 2]
  [2 3]
  [5 6]]]

