# Confusion about numpy strides

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am looking at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099870/4699994) to this question and can't wrap my head around how the `as_strided` function is viewing this array.

This piece of code is part of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099870/4699994):

```py
>>> a = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(np.array([1, 512, 0, 3], dtype=np.int16), 
                                        shape=(3,), strides=(3,))
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int16)

>>> a.strides[0]
3

>>> a.itemsize
2
```

Assuming each element of the passed array is 2 bytes long, we have the following byte representation of the array:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          |        512          |        0            |          3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000 0000 0000 0001 | 0000 0010 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 0000 0011
```

So, considering each element to be read is of 2 bytes and the stride to reach the next element is 3 bytes:

1. the first element read is `1` (`0000 0000 0000 0001`),
2. the second element to be read is after skipping 3 bytes comes out to be `0` (`0000 0000 | 0000 0000`), *half are bytes from the number `512` and the other half from the number `0`*
3. the last element to be read after another stride of 3 bytes is `3`: `0000 0000 0000 0011`

So, where am I going wrong? how is the middle element `2` in the strided output and not `0`

Comment: In most uses the `as_strided` strides will be a multiple of the base strides of the input, in this case 2.  Using 3 is deliberately asking for confusion.

Comment: Yeah, I do understand that which why this example seemed interesting to me as it was manipulating the bits and bytes change the underlying data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The little-endian memory layout of `np.array([1, 512, 0, 3], dtype=np.int16)` actually looks like this in memory (due to being little-endian, the individual entry bytes are actually in the reverse order from how you would write them):

```
(value)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1           |        512           |         0            |          3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000 0001  0000 0000 | 0000 0000  0000 0010 | 0000 0000  0000 0000 | 0000 0011  0000 0000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        0          1           2          3           4          5           6          7
(byte number)
```

`stride=3` means to move 3 bytes between items, so you'll get byte numbers `0-1`, `3-4`, `6-7`.

These are `0000 0001  0000 0000`, `0000 0010  0000 0000`, `0000 0011  0000 0000`, again interpreted as little-endian.

> The strides of an array tell us how many bytes we have to skip in memory to move to the next position along a certain axis.
>
> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html

Comment: Sheesh! Thanks a bunch, I've spent considerable time figuring this out and completely looked over the "Endianness" of the underlying data.