# When would you use `flatten()` instead of`reshape(-1)`?

Tags: python, numpy

Often, when numpy has seemingly duplicate functions, there often ends up being some sort of unique purpose for one or the other.

I am trying to figure out if there are any situations where  `flatten()` should be used instead of `reshape(-1)`

Comment: There's another choice, `np.ravel` (and its method).  I tend to prefer it; it's closer to the `reshape` in behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`flatten` [returns a copy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) of the array. `reshape` will return a view if possible.
So, for example, if `y = x.reshape(-1)` is a view, then modifying `y` also modifies `x`:

```
In [149]: x = np.arange(3)

In [150]: y = x.reshape(-1)

In [151]: y[0] = 99

In [152]: x
Out[152]: array([99,  1,  2])
```

But since `y = x.flatten()` is a copy, modifying `y` will never modify `x`:

```
In [153]: x = np.arange(3)

In [154]: y = x.flatten()

In [155]: y[0] = 99

In [156]: x
Out[156]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

---

Here is an example of when `reshape` returns a copy instead of a view:

```
In [161]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)[::2, :]

In [163]: y = x.reshape(-1)

In [164]: y[0] = 99

In [165]: x
Out[165]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

Since `x` is unaffected by an assignment made to `y`, we know `y` is a copy of
`x`, not a view.

Comment: So there 3rd example is fictional, for the purpose of demonstrating the difference between a view and copy? It is not possible for reshape to return a copy?

Comment: It's not fiction. (But don't take my word for it; try the example yourself!) `x.reshape(-1)` can return a copy, in particular, when there is no single constant that can describe the [stride of the 1D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53097952/190597).

Comment: @SantoshGupta7, `np.reshape` documents the alternative `arr.shape=-1` which acts in-place, and raises an error if a no-copy reshape is impossible.

Comment: What about expand_dims()?