# reshaping numpy array into small subslices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array in numpy, as this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to reshape it like that:

```
[[1,2,3],
[2,3,4],
[3,4,5],
[4,5,6],
[6,7,8],
[7,8,9],
[8,9,10]]
```

what is the most efficient way to do that?

What I'm currently doing is a loop using np.append, but this takes very long.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy stride tricks ([`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html)) to create a new view of the array. This will be faster than any list comprehension because no data are copied. The [IPython Cookbook has more examples](https://ipython-books.github.io/46-using-stride-tricks-with-numpy/) of using stride tricks.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
bytes_per_item = a.dtype.itemsize
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    a, shape=(8, 3), strides=(bytes_per_item, bytes_per_item))
```

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

---

## Timed tests

This answer is orders of magnitude faster than answers here that use loops. Find the tests below (done in Jupyter Notebook with `%timeit` magic). Note that one of the functions does not work properly with numpy arrays and requires a Python list.

### Setup

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 100001, dtype=np.int64)
a_list = a.tolist()

def jakub(a, shape):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    bytes_per_item = a.dtype.itemsize
    # The docs for this function recommend setting `writeable=False` to
    # prevent modifying the underlying array.
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        a, shape=shape, strides=(bytes_per_item, bytes_per_item), writeable=False)

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426256/5666087
def daveldito(arr):
    return np.array([arr[each:each+2]+[arr[each+2]] for each in range(len(arr)-2)])

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426205/5666087
def akshay_sehgal(a):
    return np.array([i for i in zip(a,a[1:],a[2:])])
```

### Results

```
%timeit jakub(a, shape=(a.shape[0]-2, 3))
8.85 µs ± 425 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit daveldito(a_list)
141 ms ± 8.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit akshay_sehgal(a)
168 ms ± 9.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do a 3 gram iteration on the list is by using a `zip`

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
np.array([i for i in zip(a,a[1:],a[2:])])
```

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

A general function to solve n-gram iterations can be made using the following -

```
def find_ngrams(input_list, n):
    return np.array(list(zip(*[input_list[i:] for i in range(n)])))

find_ngrams(a, 3) #try setting n to other values like 2 or 4 or 5
```

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

```
find_ngrams(a, 5)
```

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it as follows (note that I rely on basic list comprehension alone):

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
np.array([arr[each:each+2]+[arr[each+2]] for each in range(len(arr)-2)])
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

As for performance, for `100_000` elements in `arr`, my late 2016 MacBook Pro gives the following time stats:

> CPU times: user 148 ms, sys: 26.1 ms, total: 174 ms
> Wall time: 186 ms

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

newshape = x.shape[:-1] + (x.shape[-1] - 3 + 1, 3)
a = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=newshape, strides=x.strides + (x.strides[-1],))
```

returns

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

You can read more about that topic for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097952/how-to-understand-numpy-strides-for-layman).

Comment: You can use `strides=x.strides + x.strides[-1:]` so you don't need as many parentheses.