# Reshaping a matrix in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following matrix:

```
x = np.array([["a","b","c","d"], ["e","f","g","h"], ["i","j","k","l"], ["m","n","o","p"]])
[['a' 'b' 'c' 'd']
 ['e' 'f' 'g' 'h']
 ['i' 'j' 'k' 'l']
 ['m' 'n' 'o' 'p']]
```

How do I reshape to:

```
[['a' 'b' 'e' 'f']
 ['c' 'd' 'g' 'h']
 ['i' 'j' 'm' 'n']
 ['k' 'l' 'o' 'p']]
```

It tried

```
np.array([x.reshape(2,2) for x in x]).reshape(4,4)
```

but it just gives me the original matrix back.

Comment: `x.reshape((2, 2, 2, 2)).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(4, 4)`

Comment: @psidom That's neat! Didn't know about `swapaxes`

Comment: what do the indices correspond into the first reshape? are you changing each matrix to a 2x2 beforehand? so each 2 is for an entry in x?

Comment: the reason I want to know is because I actually have six arrays in the original x which I need to reshape into a 6x6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
x = np.array([["a","b","c","d"], ["e","f","g","h"], ["i","j","k","l"], ["m","n","o","p"]])
y = as_strided(x, shape=(2, 2, 2, 2),
    strides=(8*x.itemsize, 2*x.itemsize, 4*x.itemsize,x.itemsize)
).reshape(x.shape).copy()

print(y)
```

Prints:

```
array([['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'],
       ['c', 'd', 'g', 'h'],
       ['i', 'j', 'm', 'n'],
       ['k', 'l', 'o', 'p']], dtype='<U1')
```

With `as_strided` we can make the original array into an array containing 4 `2x2` blocks:

```
>>> as_strided(x, shape=(2, 2, 2, 2),
    strides=(8*x.itemsize, 2*x.itemsize, 4*x.itemsize,x.itemsize)
)

array([[[['a', 'b'],
         ['e', 'f']],

        [['c', 'd'],
         ['g', 'h']]],


       [[['i', 'j'],
         ['m', 'n']],

        [['k', 'l'],
         ['o', 'p']]]], dtype='<U1')
```

You can learn more about `as_strided` in detail, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097952/how-to-understand-numpy-strides-for-layman)