# Is there any way to create a tensor with a specific pattern in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I'm working with linear transformation in the form of Y=Q(X+A), where X is the input tensor and Y is the output, Q and A are two tensors to be learned. Q is an arbitrary tensor, therefore I can use `nn.Linear`. But A is a (differentiable) tensor that has some specific pattern, as a short example,

```
A = [[a0,a1,a2,a2,a2], 
     [a1,a0,a1,a2,a2],
     [a2,a1,a0,a1,a2],
     [a2,a2,a1,a0,a1],
     [a2,a2,a2,a1,a0]].
```

So I cannot define such a pattern in `nn.Linear`. Is there any way to define such a tensor in Pytorch?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). A possible implementation in PyTorch is:

```
def toeplitz(c, r):
    vals = torch.cat((r, c[1:].flip(0)))
    shape = len(c), len(r)
    i, j = torch.ones(*shape).nonzero().T
    return vals[j-i].reshape(*shape)
```

In your case with `a0` as `0`, `a1` as `1` and `a2` as `2`:

```
>>> toeplitz(torch.tensor([0,1,2,2,2]), torch.tensor([0,1,2,2,2]))
tensor([[0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        [1, 0, 1, 2, 2],
        [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
        [2, 2, 1, 0, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 0]])
```

*For a more detailed explanation refer to my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896578/pytorchs-torch-as-strided-with-negative-strides-for-making-a-toeplitz-matrix/68899386#68899386).*

Comment: I would like to update all elements with the same name together during backpropagation. For example, after one step, all `a0` are still the same.

Comment: @Zouzou Good question, this answer will indeed make a copy of `a0`, `a1` , ... since indexing makes a copy. I don't believe you can do a selection and return a view on the original data.