# Manipulating numpy arrays (concatenating inner sub-arrays)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a question of manipulating numpy arrays. Say, given a 3-d array in the form `np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]])` which is a `(2,2,2)` array. I want to manipulate it into a `(2,4)` array such that `a = np.array([[1,2,5,6],[3,4,7,8]])`. I want to know is there any built-in methods of numpy particularly dealing with problems like this and can be easily generalized.

**EDITED:**
Thank you all guys' answers. They all rock! I thought I should clarify what I mean by "easily generalized" in the original post. Suppose given a `(6,3,2,3)` array (this is the actual challenge I am facing)

```
a = array([[[[ 10,  20,  30],
         [ 40,  40,  20]],

        [[ 22,  44,  66],
         [ 88,  88,  44]],

        [[ 33,  66,  99],
         [132, 132,  66]]],


       [[[ 22,  44,  66],
         [ 88,  88,  44]],

        [[ 54, 108, 162],
         [216, 216, 108]],

        [[ 23,  46,  69],
         [ 92,  92,  46]]],


       [[[ 14,  28,  42],
         [ 56,  56,  28]],

        [[ 25,  50,  75],
         [100, 100,  50]],

        [[ 33,  66,  99],
         [132, 132,  66]]],


       [[[ 20,  40,  60],
         [ 80,  80,  40]],

        [[ 44,  88, 132],
         [176, 176,  88]],

        [[ 66, 132, 198],
         [264, 264, 132]]],


       [[[ 44,  88, 132],
         [176, 176,  88]],

        [[108, 216, 324],
         [432, 432, 216]],

        [[ 46,  92, 138],
         [184, 184,  92]]],


       [[[ 28,  56,  84],
         [112, 112,  56]],

        [[ 50, 100, 150],
         [200, 200, 100]],

        [[ 66, 132, 198],
         [264, 264, 132]]]])
```

I want to massage it into a `(3,3,2,2,3)` array such that for`a[0,:,:,:,:]`

```
a[0,0,0,:,:] = np.array([[10,20,30],[40,40,20]]);
a[0,1,0,:,:] = np.array([[22,44,66],[88,88,44]]);
a[0,2,0,:,:] = np.array([[33,66,99],[132,132,66]]);
a[0,0,1,:,:] = np.array([[20,40,60],[80,80,40]]);
a[0,1,1,:,:] = np.array([[44,88,132],[176,176,88]]);
a[0,2,1,:,:] = np.array([[66,132,198],[264,264,132]]).
```

In short, the last 3 biggest blocks should "merge" with first 3 biggest blocks to form 3 `(3,2)` blocks. The rest of 2 blocks i.e., (`a[1,:,:,:,:]`, `a[2,:,:,:,:]`) follow the same pattern.

Comment: `numpy.reshape`

Comment: Be careful with what I asked, reshape doesn't solve my problem. ```reshape``` will simply give me ```np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])```.

Comment: I don't understand how `np.reshape(a, (2,4))` is not producing exactly the expected output you show in the question.

Comment: Oh, never mind, you're mucking with the order of the values in there. OK, that was subtle. Maybe you need to do some transposing of parts of the array first? But your transposition is certainly not a standard one, so I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

Comment: I've tried many techniques, this question is harder than thought. Otherwise, I wouldn't bother to post this question.

Comment: Found a solution with `zip`, but I like Albin Paul's answer better, with `swapaxes`.

Comment: Look at `a`.  With a shape of (2,2,2), there are 3 different ways you can combine values to create a (2,4) array.  `reshape` joins the last 2 dimensions.  `reshape(4,2)` joins the first 2. You want to join the first and last, which requires reordering the elements.  Reread the `reshape` docs and pay attention to the "You can think of reshaping as first raveling the array ..." line.

Comment: "easily generalized": in which way(s)? In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69017010/758174) I put a link to the authoritative explanation for these problems.

Comment: I guess you have fell into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) tbh

Comment: I think if you simply indicate the destination address of one element with all different indices (e.g.: `orig_a[4,3,2,1]` needs to be put into `new_a[i,j,k,m]`, it would simplify the description. Ideally, to make the definition unambiguous, choose indices that are prime numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your new update, you can do the following using [np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```py
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(3,3,2,2,3), strides=(72,24,216,12,4))
array([[[[[ 10,  20,  30],
          [ 40,  40,  20]],

         [[ 20,  40,  60],
          [ 80,  80,  40]]],


        [[[ 22,  44,  66],
          [ 88,  88,  44]],

         [[ 44,  88, 132],
          [176, 176,  88]]],


        [[[ 33,  66,  99],
          [132, 132,  66]],

         [[ 66, 132, 198],
          [264, 264, 132]]]],



       [[[[ 22,  44,  66],
          [ 88,  88,  44]],

         [[ 44,  88, 132],
          [176, 176,  88]]],


        [[[ 54, 108, 162],
          [216, 216, 108]],

         [[108, 216, 324],
          [432, 432, 216]]],


        [[[ 23,  46,  69],
          [ 92,  92,  46]],

         [[ 46,  92, 138],
          [184, 184,  92]]]],



       [[[[ 14,  28,  42],
          [ 56,  56,  28]],

         [[ 28,  56,  84],
          [112, 112,  56]]],


        [[[ 25,  50,  75],
          [100, 100,  50]],

         [[ 50, 100, 150],
          [200, 200, 100]]],


        [[[ 33,  66,  99],
          [132, 132,  66]],

         [[ 66, 132, 198],
          [264, 264, 132]]]]])
```

---

Explanation:

Take another example: a small array `q` and our desired output after changing `q`:

```py
>>> q = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3,-1)
>>> q
array([[[ 0],
        [ 1],
        [ 2]],

       [[ 3],
        [ 4],
        [ 5]],

       [[ 6],
        [ 7],
        [ 8]],

       [[ 9],
        [10],
        [11]]])
# desired output:
# shape = (2, 3, 2)
array([[[ 0,  6],
        [ 1,  7],
        [ 2,  8]],

       [[ 3,  9],
        [ 4, 10],
        [ 5, 11]]])
```

Here we are using [numpy strides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097952/how-to-understand-numpy-strides-for-layman) to achieve this. Let's check for `q`'s strides:

```py
>>> q.strides
(12, 4, 4)
```

In our output, all strides should remain the same, except the third stride, because in the third dimension we need to stack with the values from bottom half of `q`, ie: `6` is put next to `0`, `7` next to `1` and so on...

So, how "far" is it from `0` to `6` ? Or in another word, how far is it from `q[0,0,0]` to `q[2,0,0]` ?

```py
# obviously, distance = [2,0,0] - [0,0,0] = [2,0,0]
bytedistance = np.sum(np.array([2,0,0])*q.strides)
# 2*12 + 0*4 + 0*4 = 24 bytes
```

Okay then `new_strides = (12, 4, 24)` and hence we got:

```py
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(q, shape=(2,3,2), strides=new_strides)
array([[[ 0,  6],
        [ 1,  7],
        [ 2,  8]],

       [[ 3,  9],
        [ 4, 10],
        [ 5, 11]]])
```

---

Back to your question:

```py
a.strides = (72,24,12,4)
new_strides = (72,24,216,12,4)     # why is 216 here ? it's a homework :)
new_a = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(3,3,2,2,3), strides=new_strides)
```

Comment: Your answer rocks. I will accept it as the most generalizable solution in my case.

Comment: @CoolGas I recommend you to read through the doc in the link above: `as_strided` is considered dangerous if used wrongly. You need to carefully calculate the strides, and if you don't, your program may crash.

Comment: Yea, totally agreed. The numpy page does stress the fact that this method should only be used in extreme case. Do appreciate that you pointed it out.

Answer (score 4):

Your subject line answers your question:

```
In [813]: a
Out[813]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
In [818]: np.concatenate(a, axis=1)    # aka np.hstack
Out[818]: 
array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 7, 8]])
```

This treats the arrays as 2 (2,2) sub-arrays.

The other concatenate option:

```
In [819]: np.concatenate(a, axis=0)
Out[819]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

I think the transpose followed by reshape is better, and more easily generalized.  But it requires some knowledge of how arrays are stored, and the meaning of the dimensions and the ways of transposing them.

The reason plain `reshape` doesn't work is that you want to reorder the elements of the array.

As documented, `reshape` effectively ravels the array, and then applies the new shape:

```
In [823]: a.ravel()
Out[823]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

but you new array has a different order:

```
In [824]: np.concatenate(a, axis=1).ravel()
Out[824]: array([1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 2):

First swapping the axes, using [np.swapaxes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy-swapaxes) and then reshaping gets the output.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]])
a = np.swapaxes(a, 0, 1)
a = np.reshape(a, (2, 4))
print(a)
```

OUTPUT

```
[[1 2 5 6]
 [3 4 7 8]]
```

You can also use [np.transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy-transpose) like `np.transpose(a, (1, 0, 2))` for swapping axes from `(0, 1, 2)` to `(1, 0, 2)` as pointed out by MadPhysicist.

Comment: You can also use `.transpose(1, 0, 2)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have updated the answer with the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case (first example), simply:

```py
>>> a.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(2, -1)
array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 7, 8]])
```

Generally speaking, I find [@Divakar mini tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/758174) to be the authoritative source for these kinds of operations.

**Edit** After the question was updated (to contain an example with a larger array), I wrote a small solver (quite fast, actually) for these kinds of questions.

Any of the following produce the same result, which meets the constraints:

```py
np.moveaxis(a.reshape(2, 3, 3, 2, 3), 0, 2)
np.rollaxis(a.reshape(2, 3, 3, 2, 3), 0, 3)
a.reshape(2, 3, 3, 2, 3).transpose(1, 2, 0, 3, 4)
a.reshape(2, 9, 6).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(3, 3, 2, 2, 3)
np.rollaxis(a.reshape(2, 9, 6), 1).reshape(3, 3, 2, 2, 3)
a.reshape(2, 9, 2, 3).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(3, 3, 2, 2, 3)
a.reshape(2, 9, 3, 2).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(3, 3, 2, 2, 3)
a.reshape(2, 9, 6).transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(3, 3, 2, 2, 3)
# ...
```

Of course, you can decide to change any single value in `.reshape()` by `-1` to "make it more generic" or more intuitive. For instance:

```py
np.rollaxis(a.reshape(2, 3, 3, 2, -1), 0, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.reshape` combined with `zip` can do what you want, but it's a bit wonky:

```
>>> a = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]])
>>> b = np.array(list(zip(a[0], a[1])))
>>> np.reshape(b, (2,4))
array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 7, 8]])
```

The challenge is that you're transposing the first and second dimension of a, which is not what `np.transpose` does. However, `zip` does that, effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hstack and vstack.

```
    a= np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]])
    s0, s1 = range(a.shape[0])
    
    x= np.vstack(np.hstack((a[s0], a[s1])))
    print(x)
```

Output

```
[[1 2 5 6]
 [3 4 7 8]]
```

Comment: `np.hstack(a)` is all you need.  It treats the arrays as a list of 2 (2,2) arrays.