# Split an N dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

every one. i want to split an array using numpy. Though i know the syntax but dimensions and axis always confuses me. So if you can give some tips and explanation, i will be thankful to you.
Let say there is a video with shape
`(128,224,224,3)`. 128 is the number of frames in the video.
Now i want to split this video into multiple videos such that each videos has 32 frames.
I do this following

```
video.reshape(len(video)//32,-1,3,224,224)
```

so the new shape is `(4,32,224,224,3)`.
Which mean that the whole video is spli into 4 parts.
The first part has first 32 frame, second part has 32 to 64 frames, third part has 64 to 96 frames as so on.
But i am confused about the order of frames.
Some time i think the syntax should be

```
video.reshape(32,-1,3,224,224)
```

which result in same of `(32,4,3,224,224)`
But i am not sure which one is correct.
Looking for some intuitive answer, though i think first ones correct, but it confuses me always.

Comment: `video.reshape(-1,32,224,224,3)`. This will create an array of *4 videos*, each with *32 frames*, *224x224 pixels* with *3 RGB values*

Comment: video.reshape(len(video)//32,-1,3,224,224) --> you are dividing video into 4 continuous (32,3,224,224) arrays. 
video.reshape(4,3,224,224) --> you are dividing video into 32 continuous (4,3,224,224) arrays. 

you need to understand the concept of strides. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097952/how-to-understand-numpy-strides-for-layman question for better understanding. Numpy arrays are by default stored in contiguous 1D C arrays( refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays).