# Appending a series of 2d numpy array to create a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I thought this was an easy problem, but I have been struggling with it.

I have a dataframe with 4 columns (Open, High, Low, Close).

I need to iteratively select

- for 100 times
- a batch of 75 rows
- each having 4 columns.
  Such that the final shape is (100,75,4)

I have tried `np.append, np.stack, np.dstack, np.concatenate`. None of it works.

In `np.append` i get a shape (7500,4)

In `np.stack` in the second iteration there is error that all input arrays must have the same shape (since after first stack the original arrays shape is different).

My last code with `np.stack` (not put other attempts):

```
for i in range (100):
  print(i)
  if (i==0):
    temp_array=timeseries[['Open','High','Low','Close']].iloc[i:i+75].to_numpy()
  else:
    temp_temp_array=np.stack([temp_array,timeseries[['Open','High','Low','Close']].iloc[i:i+75].to_numpy()])
    temp_array=temp_temp_array
  print(temp_array.shape)
```

It seems stackoverflow/internet does not have an answer (or may be I am not asking the right questions).

Comment: `np.array([df.iloc[i:i+75].to_numpy() for i in range(100)])`, could be improved with `as_stride` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Quang, you can use strides here for speed and memory (!) efficiency:

```py
X = df.values
rolling_X = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X, shape=(X.shape[0],75,X.shape[1]), strides=(X.strides[0], X.strides[0], X.strides[1]))
```

edit:

To mask out some columns, you can do it on the dataframe first:

```py
X = df[['High']].values
```

or, for speed, you can use numpy index lookups:

```py
X = df.values[:,[1]]
```

Comment: Wow thanks!!! Magic! Cant understand much of it, but wow. A followup query - If I wanted just one column from X.. lets say X['High'] what changed shud i do. Code isnt working for that.

Comment: Have edited my post to answer your query, let me know if you want to know more

Comment: Btw, here is a insightfult comment to understand the underlying "magic" (it's not) https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099870/3275464