# Numpy large square matrix with repetition

Tags: python, numpy

I need to construct a large square `N*M` by `N*M` matrix to be used with `numpy.matmul`. There is a lot of repetition, such that the elements of each `M` by `M` square segment are repeated `N*N` times. To illustrate, for `M=2` and `N=3`:

```
s = np.array([[1,2], 
              [3,4]])
S = np.array([1,2,1,2,1,2],
             [3,4,3,4,3,4],
             [1,2,1,2,1,2],
             [3,4,3,4,3,4],
             [1,2,1,2,1,2],
             [3,4,3,4,3,4],)
```

The idea here is to construct `S` as a view of `s`, in order to use less memory. This is my attempt at doing it using a combination of `broadcast_to` and `reshape`. Essentially, I am trying to "broadcast" a `M x M` matrix to a `N*M x N*M` one.

```
import numpy

N = 10000
M = 10

w = numpy.random.rand(N*M, 1)
s = numpy.random.rand(M, M)

S4d = numpy.broadcast_to(s, shape=(N, N, M, M))
S = S4d.reshape(N*M, N*M)
```

Output:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 74.5 GiB for an array with shape (10000, 10000, 10, 10) and data type float64
```

Is there a way to construct matrix `S` as described above?

One workaround would be to write a function to do matrix multiplication for this case. But considering real-life values of `M ~ 1e3, N ~ 1e4`, I expect `w' * S * w` to take `O(1e14)` operations which would be slow.

**Edit**
I realized that `w' * S * w` can be broken down into multiplications of slices of `w` with `s`. The whole product computes in just over 1 second. However, I would still be curious to know if there is a way to construct `S` as a view of `s`.

Comment: while `S4d` is a view (my guess, I'd like to see the shape strides), the reshape will create a copy.  That's where you get the memory error (a full error traceback should confirm that.

Comment: Correct, `S4d` is a view, which can be verified by looking at `S4d.base`.

Answer (score 2):

`S` cannot be created as a view of `s`. A NumPy array requires consistent *strides* - the distance in memory between elements must be consistent along a dimension. Creating `S` as a view would require strides to change repeatedly within a single dimension.

Comment: Is it to enable constant-time index look-up? This could be done by introducing a look-up function that will map index to correct memory location, knowing how the view is laid out. I am curious why it's not done this way. Where can I read about it in more detail?

Comment: @user443854: Introducing such a function would cause a multiple order of magnitude slowdown.

Comment: @user2357112 I recommend reading [How to understand numpy strides for layman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097952/how-to-understand-numpy-strides-for-layman) to understand why NumPy strides are implemented in the manner they are.