# Select columns of a matrix out of rows indexes contained in an array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say that I have a matrix with a given dimension, and also one array that contains a range of values. The values contained in the array are the indexes of the rows in which I want to extract the values out of my matrix. So, an example could be:

```
A = np.array([[3, 6, 7, 5, -3, 0], [5, -2, 2, 51, -13, 8], [13, -17, 18, 22, -12, 90], [33, -12, 12, 32, -42, 90]])

B = np.array([0, 2, 3])
```

the result expected:

```
array([[ 3,  7,  5],
       [ 5,  2, 51],
       [13, 18, 22],
       [33, 12, 32]])
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as it's a matter of basic NumPy functionality. This information is easily accessible in the numpy docs, and in at least one duplicate question, as such I can't see it being useful to any future readers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the ith column of a NumPy multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/how-to-access-the-ith-column-of-a-numpy-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty simple in `numpy`- just do:

```py
A[:, B]
```

Some useful ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html