# how do you create subarray from 1st column of a 2d array in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Using numpy, how is it possible to take the array

`np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`

and get out the arrays

`[1,4,7] and [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the ith column of a NumPy multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/how-to-access-the-ith-column-of-a-numpy-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Downvoting because you have not done any research or read any introductory materials before asking. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing as such :

```
In [9]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [10]: a[:,0]
Out[10]: array([1, 4, 7])

In [11]: a[:,1:]
Out[11]:
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 6],
       [8, 9]])
```