# Splitting array into multiple ones

Tags: python, arrays, split

I'd like to split my array into multiple ones: The original array looks as follows:

```
array([[228.6311346 , 228.6311346 , 228.6311346 ],
       [418.57914851,   0.        , 228.321311  ],
       [416.83133465,   0.        , 723.25171282]])
```

The resulting arrays should look like this:

```
array1([228.6311346, 418.57914851, 416.83133465])
array2([228.6311346, 0., 0.])
array3([228.6311346, 228.321311, 723.25171282])
```

Comment: Hmm would you like them to be printed or to be assigned to a variable?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html  `np.hsplit(x,3)`

Comment: These are numpy arrays?  You can use `array1 = array[0,:]` and `array2 = array[1,:]`, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the ith column of a NumPy multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/how-to-access-the-ith-column-of-a-numpy-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @Theshape As I have to do calculations later on, I think assigned to a variable.

Comment: @TimRoberts the other way around

Comment: @Chris exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    exec("array"+str(i+1)+"=array["+str(i)+"]")
```

It will create your variable dynamically and assign the corresponding value to it.

```
array = [[1],[2],[3]]
print(array0) // outputs [1] after running above code
```

You can also use numpy.hsplit [Doc Here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html)

```
numpy.hsplit(ary, indices_or_sections)
# Split an array into multiple sub-arrays of equal size.
```

Comment: `split`/`hsplit` is the correct answer.  `exec` is a bad idea (despite the fact that it more closely matches OP's desired output).