# NumPy will not slice array column, only the row

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numpy-ndarray

I am having trouble slicing the below NumPy array. I want to pull out the first column. I have tried almost every combination and cannot slice the column I want; it always slices the row.

```py
print(solved_thetas())
# >>> array([[1.72, 3.04],
#            [0.50, -2.01]], dtype=object)
print(solved_thetas()[0][:])
# >>> array([1.72, 3.04], dtype=object)
print(solved_thetas()[:][0])
# >>> array([1.72, 3.04], dtype=object)
```

I was expecting to slice the first column of my solved_thetas() array.

Comment: Have you tried `[:, 0]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access the ith column of a NumPy multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/how-do-i-access-the-ith-column-of-a-numpy-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> n
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

You can get the values from the first column thusly:

```
>>> n[:,0]
array([1, 3])
```

For the second:

```
>>> n[:,1]
array([2, 4])
```

Or with the ellipses form:

```
>>> n[...,0]
array([1, 3])
>>> n[...,1]
array([2, 4])
```

If you want to maintain the dimensionality, you can do:

```
>>> n[:,:1]
array([[1],
       [3]])

>>> n[:,1:2]
array([[2],
       [4]])
```

Read the [basics on indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) ndarrays and [dimensional indexing tools](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#dimensional-indexing-tools).

---

The reason your attempt does not work is that each `[]` is evaluated separately. Your try of `array[0]` returns the first row and `array[0][:]` is just of a copy of `array[0]`. Same if you reverse them.